# Scroll UICollectionView (horizontally)

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to scroll `UICollectionView` cells horizontally from right to left. Each cell contains an `UIImage` stored in an array. I am using the following function

```
var index: Int = 0
var timer : Timer!

 timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(scrollToNext), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func scrollToNext() {
    index += 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}
```

All of the cells are scrolling perfectly except last 5/6 cells. Suppose, array contains 9 images. First 3 images are scrolled but last 6 images are not scrolled. Those last 6 images are in the visible rect of `UICollectionView`. What is the problem? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540084/how-to-scroll-uicollectionviewcell-programmatically-in-ios/21542766#21542766

Comment: thanks. I tried that but it scrolled all visible cells at a time(in my case it scrolled 5 cells at a time). I need to scroll cell by cell that my code does but last 5/6 visible cells are not scrolling. When there remaining last 5/6 cells my cell by cell scrolling pauses. Any idea how to solve this? @MDB983

Comment: @pigeon_39 you can scroll using the setContentOffset using the index and the width of your cells

Comment: can you help me with a bit of code ? @ReinierMelian